# Can you have multiple itemprop=description on a page?

Tags: html, microdata, rich-snippets

I can't seem to find the answer for this anywhere.

I've got `itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review"` on the body tag.

Now the content on the page is spread across multiple divs with images and such between. If I were to wrap it all, then other content would actually come first before the main body, so I need to be able to put the `itemprop="description"` on multiple divs.

It seems to show up OK in the google snippets tool but I want to know if it would be fine or whether it'd only take 1 into account?

[image: Picture of rich snippets tool]

Answer (score 5):

Well, you are adding *several* descriptions for the same item. That’s fine from the Microdata perspective.

Microdata only [defines that an item’s properties with the same name are *ordered*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#names:-the-itemprop-attribute) (see the examples), while different properties are "unordered with respect to each other".

[Microdata does not define](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#associating-names-with-items) if this should mean that all these descriptions should be consolidated into one description (your use case), or if these are alternative descriptions (for example one could offer descriptions in several languages).

But how consumers (like Google) interpret this, that is up to them; it might be unknown/undocumented; it might change daily. Discussion about this is probably off-topic on SO; it might better fit on [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you want itemprop="description" on multiple div elements
[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090825/microdata.html) you can see itemprop="name" on multiple span elements for example, so it might be ok