# Is it possible to use two names for a person in schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

I'm using [schema.org](http://schema.org/) in my website.

When I want to name a person there is no problem, but I have to give that two names (one in English global language and another in local language).

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply [use the corresponding property several times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21239191/1591669) for the same item.

Example in Microdata:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <div itemprop="name">John</div>
  <div itemprop="name">Johannes</div>
</div>
```

(Note that there is also the [`alternateName`](http://schema.org/alternateName) property.)

You may want to use the `lang` attribute to specify the language.

Comment: Great. I'll use it. But could you write an example with language attribute?

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri: Simply add the `lang` attribute to the element containing the name, e.g.: `<div itemprop="name" lang="en">John</div>` (if "John" would be in English). Note that this has nothing to do with Microdata or schema.org, that’s plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

How about using either the "givenName" or "alternateName" property?

Comment: I use givenName. could I use both of them into an item? it wont make any problems? which one is better for local and global language?