# multiple authors or contributors in schema.org

Tags: schema.org

If one looks at the [Movie](https://schema.org/Movie) type in schema.org, both `actor` and `actors` properties are allowed (actor supersedes actors). But there is no equivalent for `author` and `contributor` properties. In my view, a News Article for example, can often can have multiple authors and/or contributors.

The `orderedItem` property in [Order](https://schema.org/Order) allows for a single OrderItem/Product, or a collection of OrderItems/Products. Can we do the same with the `author` and `contributor` properties, ie. save multiple entities in a collection?

Comment: (1) Did you really mean `actor` in the sentence "But there is no equivalent for `actor` […]"? (2) How can `orderedItem` have "a collection of OrderItems/Products" as value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a property multiple times.

For example, a `Movie` could have two `actor`s:

```html
<article typeof="schema:Movie">
  <ul>
    <li property="schema:actor" typeof="schema:Person">…</li>
    <li property="schema:actor" typeof="schema:Person">…</li>
  </ul>      
</article>
```

Or a [`Person` could have two `name`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21365575/1591669).