# Which is the correct way to mark tags in an article using schema.org?

Tags: seo, keyword, schema.org, structured-data

I have found the following 3 ways, but it's not clear which is the correct one, or are all of them correct? Should I even be marking tags in my articles? I'm especially concerned about SEO issues.

```
<meta itemprop="Keywords" content="tag1, tag2, tag3"/>
<a href="link1">tag1</a>, <a href="link2">tag2</a>, <a href="link3">tag3</a>
```

or

```
<a href="link1"><span itemprop="Keywords">tag1</span></a>, <a href="link2"><span itemprop="Keywords">tag2</span></a>, <a href="link3"><span itemprop="Keywords">tag3</span></a>
```

or

```
<span itemprop="Keywords"><a href="link1">tag1</a>, <a href="link2">tag2</a>, <a href="link3">tag3</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: You have to use [`keywords`](http://schema.org/keywords), not `Keywords`. Schema.org terms are case-sensitive.

Usually, a Schema.org property only takes one value. If you want to provide several values for a property, you’d have to add [the same property several times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21239191/1591669).

However, the [`keywords` property](http://schema.org/keywords) is an exception (because it is modeled after HTML’s `keywords` name for `meta` elements): it can contain multiple keywords.

To make this exception clear, its description contains:

> Multiple entries in a keywords list are typically delimited by commas.

So two of your examples are in line with this definition:

```html
<meta itemprop="keywords" content="tag1, tag2, tag3" />
```

```html
<span itemprop="keywords"><a href="link1">tag1</a>, <a href="link2">tag2</a>, <a href="link3">tag3</a></span>
```

However, I’d expect parsers to handle this case correctly, too (as they have to do it with all other properties anyway), similar to having [several `meta`-`keywords` elements](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54979/17633) in the same document:

```html
<a href="link1"><span itemprop="keywords">tag1</span></a>, <a href="link2"><span itemprop="keywords">tag2</span></a>, <a href="link3"><span itemprop="keywords">tag3</span></a>
```